# Nodejs Browserify Uncaught TypeError: exists is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

I am new to Browserify and trying the following:
I created a node server and trying to get a package called 'openbci' running on the browser.

so I have the following file structure:

```
Myapp
-...
-public
--app.js
--index.html
--openBCI.js
--...
--javascript
---openBCI
----bundle.js
---...
-node_modules
--openbci
---openBCIBoard.js
--browserify
--...
```

my `app.js` file sets the server to serve the `public` folder

```
// app.js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.listen(myPort);
```

then I created the following `openBCI.js`

```
// openBCI.js
var OpenBCIBoard = require('openbci').OpenBCIBoard;
exports.OpenBCIBoard = OpenBCIBoard;
```

and finally launched the browserify command:

```
$ browserify public/openBCI.js > public/javascript/openBCI/bundle.js
```

but once called in my `index.html` file, I got an `Uncaught TypeError: exists is not a function` at Function.getRoot:

```
exports.getRoot = function getRoot (file) {
  var dir = dirname(file)
    , prev
  while (true) {
    if (dir === '.') {
      // Avoids an infinite loop in rare cases, like the REPL
      dir = process.cwd()
    }
    **if (exists(join(dir, 'package.json')) || exists(join(dir, 'node_modules'))) {**
      // Found the 'package.json' file or 'node_modules' dir; we're done
      return dir
    }
    if (prev === dir) {
      // Got to the top
      throw new Error('Could not find module root given file: "' + file
                    + '". Do you have a `package.json` file? ')
    }
    // Try the parent dir next
    prev = dir
    dir = join(dir, '..')
  }
}
```

It appears that it could not find the original path for the module.
Could you please tell me what is to change? Or if I understood at all how browserify works ? :)

Answer (score 0):

I notice a few things that seem strange about the code.

1. `exists` is undefined in JavaScript or node.  It appears to be an alias of `fs.exists` - is that right?

If so, fs.exists is deprecated.  Per the documentation, you can achieve the same effect with `fs.stat` or `fs.access`.  Note however that you should either supply a callback (preferable) or use the Sync version of these methods.

2. If you are trying to use file system tools in the browser you are going to run into problems because you are attempting to access the server's file system from the browser.  There is a plugin, [browserify-fs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserify-fs), that gives you an equivalent to fs in the browser.  However, this seems to access the browser's local IndexedDB, not the storage on your server.

I would suggest running code that relies on server-side files on the server, rather than in the browser.